# Iterator with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

I need to implement an `Iterator` that returns two values (nothing unusual so far), but these values need to be continuously computed/generated in parallel, even when the iterator is not solicited.

Here is an example to explain what I need.

```
def GenerateValues()
    #I do the math for value1 in the first thread
    #I do the math for value2 in the second thread
    return value1 value2

def myIterator()
    while 1:
        yield GenerateValues()
```

In this situation, `value1` and `value2` are computed/generated in parallel only when the function myIterator is called. But in my problem, it takes a **long time** to compute/generate `value1` and `value2`, but it also takes a **very long time** to process `value1` and `value2`. So when my software is processing `value1` and `value2`, I would like it to compute in parallel the new `value1` and new `value2`.

So it would be something like:

```
def GenerateValues()
    #If value1 and value 2 are not computed, then wait.

    #I do the math for the new value1 in the first thread without blocking
    #I do the math for the new value2 in the second thread without blocking
    return value1 value2

def myIterator()
    while 1:
        yield GenerateValues()
```

With such configuration, the new `value1` and new `value2` are computed/generated while `value1` and `value2` are returned to be processed.

- Is that clear enough?
- If yes, how could I do such synchronization?

Thanks in advance for your help!

PS: I need the `while 1`, no need to comment on that point.

Comment: Have you considered to use `multiprocessing.Pool` and `map` myIterator?

Comment: I am new in Python, how would I use them?

Comment: Have you deleted your answer?

Comment: I did, you said it was not what you were looking for. I can undelete it if you think it may be useful.

Comment: I said I was not sure :-) Sorry if my question was not clear enough. But indeed, I think you gave me a parallel computation of two values when I need a parallel generation running in parallel of the computation

Comment: Are you trying to compute `value1` and `value2` in parallel in `GenerateValues()` ? You could do this easily with `multiprocessing` or `threading`. Or are there any other requirement?

Comment: I am still getting confused with your use of "computation" and "generation". In general, you can use Pool and map with any function you want, so you can apply it with GenerateValues instead.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I fully understand what you are trying to do, if you are trying to calculate `value1` and `value2` in parallel, you could use `multiprocessing` or `threading`. I do recommend `multiprocessing` if the task is CPU-bound, to fully take advantage of your CPU to "side-step" the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) by using subprocesses instead of threads.

This is a rather straight forward example of using `multiprocessing`:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

def cal_value1(queue):
    # do the job
    queue.put({'value1': value1})

def cal_value2(queue):
    # do the job
    queue.put({'value2': value2})

def GenerateValues()
    #If value1 and value 2 are not computed, then wait.
    queue = Queue() # 
    process_1 = Process(target=cal_value1, args=(queue, ))
    process_2 = Process(target=cal_value2, args=(queue, ))
    process_1.start()
    process_2.start()  # start both processes
    process_1.join()
    process_2.join()  # wait for both to finish

    result = queue.get()
    result.update(queue.get()) # get results

    return result['value1'], result['value2']
```

P.S. You can easily use `threading.Thread` and `Queue.Queue` to replace `multiprocessing.Process` and `multiprocessing.Queue` if you want.

**Edit:** 
Now let's make `cal_value1` and `cal_value2` long running processes, and you might want to start these 2 processes in the beginning of your script.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

def cal_value1(tasks, results):
    while True:
        task = tasks.get() # this will block until a new task coming in
        # calculate value1
        results.put({'value1': value1})

def cal_value2(tasks, results):
    while True:
        task = tasks.get() # this will block until a new task coming in
        # calculate value2
        results.put({'value2': value2})

def main(）:
    cal_value1_tasks, cal_value2_tasks, results = Queue(), Queue(), Queue()
    process_1 = Process(target=cal_value1, args=(cal_value1_tasks, results, ))
    process_2 = Process(target=cal_value2, args=(cal_value2_tasks, results, ))
    process_1.start()
    process_2.start()
    cal_value1_tasks.put('cal_value1')
    cal_value2_tasks.put('cal_value2') # Start to calculate the first pair
    values = GenerateValues(cal_value1_tasks, cal_value2_tasks, results)

def GenerateValues(cal_value1_tasks, cal_value2_tasks, results):
    values = results.get() # get results
    values.update(queue.get()) # notice that it'll block until both value1 and value 2 calculated
    cal_value1_tasks.put('cal_value1')
    cal_value2_tasks.put('cal_value2') # before returning, start to calculate the next round of value1 and value2
    return values['value1'], values['value2]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's almost what I need, except that I don't want the join() because I need to return the old value1/value2, and compute the new value1 and new value2 while the old ones are processed. It is what I wrote into my second example: #... without  blocking.

Comment: In that case, you could make `cal_value1` and `cal_value2` into long running processes to keep calculating all the time and continuously putting new values into `queue`, add a new `task_queue` (just to be convenient for you to control them), and in `GenerateValues()` use `queue.get()` to get new values (it'll block until there's a new value available)

Comment: I am a beginner in python, could you please highlight me with your example?

Answer (score 1):

In CPython (the most-used implementation that you get from python.org) threads do not really help with parallelizing *computations done in python*.

Because to make memory management easier (among other things) only *one* thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode. This is enforced by the global interpreter lock ("GIL").

(If you are doing all your calculations in an extension like `numpy`, which releases the GIL when it's working, this restriction mostly does not apply)

You could use `multiprocessing` or (or the `ProcesPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures` from python 3.2 onwards) to spread the calculation out over multiple processes. There are examples for both in the implementation.

Below is an example where I use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` to convert DICOM images to JPEG. It uses the "[wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/)" python bindings to [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/). What it does it to make a list of jobs (futures), and start those. The `as_completed` function returns the result for each future in the order that they finish.

```
def convert(filename):
    """Convert a DICOM file to a JPEG file, removing the blank areas from the
    Philips x-ray detector.

    Arguments:
        filename: name of the file to convert.

    Returns:
        Tuple of (input filename, output filename)
    """
    outname = filename.strip() + '.jpg'
    with Image(filename=filename) as img:
        with img.convert('jpg') as converted:
            converted.units = 'pixelsperinch'
            converted.resolution = (300, 300)
            converted.crop(left=232, top=0, width=1574, height=2048)
            converted.save(filename=outname)
    return filename, outname


def main(argv):
    """Main entry point for dicom2jpg.py.

    Arguments:
        argv: command line arguments
    """
    if len(argv) == 1:
        binary = os.path.basename(argv[0])
        print("{} ver. {}".format(binary, __version__), file=sys.stderr)
        print("Usage: {} [file ...]\n".format(binary), file=sys.stderr)
        print(__doc__)
        sys.exit(0)
    del argv[0]  # Remove the name of the script from the arguments.
    es = 'Finished conversion of {} to {}'
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as tp:
        fl = [tp.submit(convert, fn) for fn in argv]
        for fut in cf.as_completed(fl):
            infn, outfn = fut.result()
            print(es.format(infn, outfn))
```

You can find this and other examples in my [scripts](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts) repository on github.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Indeed, I use numpy, so the blocking does not apply. However, I work with python 2.7 because of the library I have to use.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I got your question right. Also, I don't see why you want to make an extra iterator instead of yielding directly in ComputeValues. But I will keep my example close to your code.

If so, maybe you want to try to use multiprocessing.pool like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def ComputeValues(v1,v2):
    ...
    return value1 value2 # you could just yield here!

def myIterator(x): #x is a tuple in this case
    v1,v2 = x
    while 1:
        yield ComputeValues(v1,v2)

p = Pool(5) #will spawn 5 processes, each of them will run myIterator
print(p.imap_unordered(myIterator, [(v1a,v2a), (v1b, v2b), ...]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not sure that's what I need. I think that I was not clear on my question, so I've edited it for clarification. I want to generate (and not compute) new values, while the old values are processed.

Comment: Can you add an example of input/output you expect?

Comment: Not really... I want my program to generate `new value1` and `new value2` while it is processing `value1` and `value2`. What I don't know, it's how to generate the value in parallel, because I have to generate them into the iterator without blocking it because it needs to return the already generated values.

Comment: @alec_djinn The function used for mapping should return a value, not yield it.

Comment: @RolandSmith you are right! It is still not clear for me what is the goal here. Maybe `yield p.map(ComputeValues, [(v1a,v2a), (v1b, v2b), ...])` in myIterator is the solution?

Comment: @alec_djinn `map` only returns when *all* the work is done. You should  use `imap_unordered`. That returns an iterator that starts yielding results as soon as some calculations are finished.